# Rihedit text margin

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit, wtl

How to set the richedit text's top/left margins so that it should display a text lower/farther from its top/left border by the specified distances? I write in c++.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you already checked EM_SETMARGINS message? Basically it's for Edit but it could be also sent to Rich Edit:
[EM_SETMARGINS message reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761649%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, i did. There is no effect.